# Does Zkteco SDK works with Qube biometrics?

Tags: sdk, biometrics, zkteco

I Have a program that works with class of zkemkeeper and i'm wondering if zkemkeeper can also works with other brand of biometrics like Qube QF40? If not. is there a freeware to use for the sdk of qube ?

Answer (score 0):

Qube is supporting various biometric devices procuring from various vendors. The one you referred looks like the Zk one. So you can use the zk sdk for this device. You can download the SDK from https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory.html